# $post->post_content empty while all other properties are correct

Tags: posts, functions

I'm trying to pull raw post content in order to identify if a particular shortcode is used, and if so, what its properties are.  All of the properties of my $post object return what I expect *except* for post_content, which seems to give me an empty value.  I've tried removing all markup from the body in order to avoid any potential pre-processing, but even then I get nothing.  Here's how I try for the content;

```
    $content_post = get_post($post->ID, OBJECT, 'edit');
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
```

I got the same result using

```
    $content_post = get_post($post->ID, OBJECT, 'raw');
```

Similarly trying to pull the body with

```
$post_content = get_the_content("", false, $post->ID);
```

Got me nothing.

I did also try

```
$post_content =  apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

Which got me back an empty span;

```
<span class="cp-load-after-post"></span>
```

This being my first WP project, I'm hoping I missed something simple...

Update: I do see the expected text in the post_content field in the zl_posts table.

Comment: Are you sure your posts contain content? A page builder could be storing it in post meta or another non-standard place. Also have you checked https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/ ? If you can call `$post->ID` then why do you need to retrieve it with `get_post`? Couldn't you just use `$post->post_content` and avoid the unnecessary variable and `get_post` call? Most people using `get_post` only pass the first parameter

Comment: How would I check for post meta?  I called get_post because I was in someone else's code, hoping the $post object I had was not the one I expected, causing my missing content.  Just tried get_the_content and one other, updated Q to reflect that.

Comment: Can you expand your code snippet to include all the surrounding code? What you've shared is not enough to debug this. Also, why are you trying to look for a shortcode and its properties? What's the problem that solves? ( and why didn't you ask about that problem instead? )

Comment: If you want to get post meta, you `get_post_meta`, WP isn't an object oriented application, and `WP_Post` is just a data bag, you should use the APIs at every opportunity rather than the various objects. If a function exists for it, use the function not the member variable. For that reason, it makes no sense to call `get_post` again as you already have a post object, it'll likely return the exact same object too. ***To answer this question though, you must add more code, the snippet you've shared is not enough.***